# Look, look with your special eyes!

Tags: wordplay, knowledge

> Those often confused with mongols and a week part
>   Heard on the green plus the bird of Always Sunny perhaps?
>   Merger of an act of sadness and what's found in a racist's vocabulary
>   Latino revolutionary mixed with the act of competing for
>   Crooked Bruce of martial arts?
>   The price to pay with one's location
>   A lock opener reversed
>   Leg joint and child

What do each of these clues stand for, and what do they all have in common?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Those often confused with mongols and a week part

> Huns + day = HYUNDAI

Heard on the green plus the bird of Always Sunny perhaps?

> for(e) + d(ee) = FORD

Merger of an act of sadness and what's found in a racist's vocabulary

> cry + slur = CHRYSLER

Latino revolutionary mixed with the act of competing for

> Che v. = CHEVY

Crooked Bruce of martial arts?

> Bent + Lee = BENTLEY

The price to pay with one's location

> Fee + at = FIAT

A lock opener reversed

> A Key = KIA

Leg joint and child

> knee + son = NISSAN

**The Connection**

> All of these are car manufacturers!

**Title reference:**

> [MY BRAND](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9YBwa0O1Zc)